# Async Method is triggering error when using lambda query to assign method group

Tags: c#, lambda

Here is my model below and this is a source code I downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs: I am following the instruction.

```
public class TriviaQuestion
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<TriviaOption> Options { get; set; }
}


  public class TriviaOption
    {
        [Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("TriviaQuestion")]
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual TriviaQuestion TriviaQuestion { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my controller where I am getting the error which says"q.Count cannot assign method group to anonymous type propery.  " :

```
private async Task<TriviaQuestion> NextQuestionAsync(string userId)
        {
            var lastQuestionId = await this.db.TriviaAnswers
                .Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
                .GroupBy(a => a.QuestionId)
                .Select(g => new { QuestionId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                .OrderByDescending(q => new { **q.Count**, QuestionId = q.QuestionId })
                .Select(q => q.QuestionId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            var questionsCount = await this.db.TriviaQuestions.CountAsync();

            var nextQuestionId = (lastQuestionId % questionsCount) + 1;
            return await this.db.TriviaQuestions.FindAsync(CancellationToken.None, nextQuestionId);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q.Count` is not a valid name for a field on a anonymous type, you need to give it a name like you did for QuestionId

```
.OrderByDescending(q => new { Count = q.Count, QuestionId = q.QuestionId })
```

You also could split the orderby apart in to a OrderByDecending and a ThenByDecending.

```
.OrderByDescending(q => q.Count)
.ThenByDescending(q => q.QuestionId)
```

If you are working against a IQueryable object it may end up with a better query for the server.